# Using a counter, 0 if not found

Tags: python, counter

I'm writing a script that first extracts the 50 most common words from a large collection of files. It then goes on to find how many occurences of those 50 words can be found in each file. 
This works, however it only gives a number if the word is found. I want it to give a 0 if a word is not found.
The code I have so far is the following:

```
for text in posts:
   c=counter()
   c.update(word for word in wordpunct_tokenize(text3) if word in top)
   rel_freq2= c.values()
   print rel_freq2
```

In this code, top is a list that looks like this:

```
[',', '.', 'i', '?', 'the', 'to', 'and', 'it', 'of', 'that', 'a', 'in', 'he', 'you', "'", 's', 'is', '...', '(', 'my', 't', 'be', 'for', 'what', 'with', 'so', 'now', 'have', 'm', 'we', 'this', '!', 'get', 'all', 'if', 'was', 'but', 'me', 'not', '"', 'about', 'on', 'they', '-', 'why', 'love', 'one', 'going', 'iraq', 'can']
```

The outcome of the script is something like this:

```
[11, 1, 11, 15, 8, 11, 6, 3, 11, 4, 10, 11, 10, 4, 21, 38, 19, 1, 8, 1, 56, 5, 5, 7, 

13, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 20, 4, 5, 9, 19, 9, 38, 10, 8, 12, 23, 8]
[5, 2, 2, 7, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 11, 1, 7, 19, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 16, 2, 2, 3, 4]
[19, 4, 6, 12, 5, 8, 1, 4, 13, 3, 1, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 25, 8, 24, 3, 7, 2, 7, 6, 10, 12, 1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1, 8, 1, 1, 2, 23, 6, 2, 1, 1, 2, 13, 3]
[6, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 6, 6, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 1, 9, 2]
```

Notice that there are no 0's here.
Every list need 50 items in it, 0's or higher.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the values for all 50 words in some list of words, even the ones that never appear:

```
rel_freq2 = [c.get(word, 0) for word in top]
```

This also has the advantage that it comes out in order of your word list, instead of in arbitrary and unpredictable order like `c.values()`.

The [`get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method lets you supply a default value for keys that aren't available. If your `counter` class is similar to the standard [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), there's already a default of `0`, so you don't need this, and can instead just do `c[word]`.

Comment: Meaning that my code would become:

for text in posts:
   c=counter()
   c.update(word for word in wordpunct_tokenize(text3) if word in          top)
   rel_freq2= [c.get(word, 0) for word in words
   print rel_freq2
Or does it come before the counter line?

Comment: @Nikolaas: Your first version is right. Just replace `rel_freq2= c.values()` with `rel_freq2 = [c.get(word, 0) for word in top]`, and leave everything in the same order. (How could it come before the `counter` line, if it uses the `counter` instance `c`?)

Answer (score 0):

if Python 2.7 is an option, use [Counter from the standary library instead](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
 from collections import Counter
 posts = ['the', 'to', 'xyz', 'abc']
 top = [',', '.', 'i', '?', 'the', 'to', 'and', 'it', 'of', 'that', 'a', 'in', 'he', 'you', "'", 's', 'is', '...', '(', 'my', 't', 'be', 'for', 'what', 'with', 'so', 'now', 'have', 'm', 'we', 'this', '!', 'get', 'all', 'if', 'was', 'but', 'me', 'not', '"', 'about', 'on', 'they', '-', 'why', 'love', 'one', 'going', 'iraq', 'can']
 c = Counter(posts)
 for x in top:
   print x, c[x]
```